# What is the mathematical term for "incarnation," "form," or "version"?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word escapes me for some reason.

Here's a sample (jocose) sentence:

> "He must have been a capable psychologist in some (???)."

Meaning - in a different life, perhaps.

I think it's a mathematical term. I may be wrong.

Comment: How do dictionaries define 'incarnation'? And how can the example sentence be considered to need a mathematical term (which your title question clearly requests?)

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. As are questions where at least some obvious research is not presented.

Comment: Did a thesaurus suggest any possibilities? How about 'in some other life' or 'in some former life'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I honestly don't know. The word is at the tip of my tongue. It's very frustrating.

Comment: Perhaps your title should be 'What is another term for “other incarnation,” “other form,” or “alternative version”, quite possibly also used in the mathematics domain?'?

Comment: The only math-y word I know that might apply is "permutation".

Comment: He must have been a capable psychologist in some inKantation? Incantation can be used to refer to the thing conjured into existence as well as the act of conjuring.

Comment: _Dimension_ perhaps. [_Wiktionary_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dimension) definition: "(science fiction, fantasy) An alternative universe or plane of existence."

Comment: A true guessing game. Perhaps *instantiation*  or *instance*, you don't really provide any clues. Are you saying he is not a psychologist now, but he has all the skills to be a good one? Or, are you saying he is a bad psychologist, but perhaps in his past he was a good one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For something mathematical, consider [**iteration**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/iteration):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : the action or a process of iterating or repeating: such as
>   **a** : a procedure in which repetition of a sequence of operations yields results successively closer to a desired result
>   **b** : the repetition of a sequence of computer instructions a specified number of times or until a condition is met — compare RECURSION
>   **2** : one execution of a sequence of operations or instructions in an iteration
>   **3** : version, incarnation · the latest *iteration* of the operating system

So:

> He must have been a capable psychologist in (some / a previous) *iteration*.

It would be particularly appropriate in the context of reincarnation.

Answer (score 3):

universe

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universe_(mathematics)):

> a collection that contains all the entities one wishes to consider in a given situation

In your example:

> He must have been a capable psychologist in some universe.

it would mean from a collection of psychologists and perhaps non-psychologists he is believed to be part of the subset of *capable psychologists*.

Answer (score 0):

> "He must have been a capable psychologist in some parallel universe."

**[parallel universe](https://www.theguardian.com/science/across-the-universe/2017/may/17/multiverse-have-astronomers-found-evidence-of-parallel-universes)**

> They call it the *[**multiverse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiverse)*. It’s a cosmos in which there are multiple universes. And by multiple, I mean an infinite number. These uncountable realms sit side by side in higher dimensions that our senses are incapable of perceiving directly.
>
> Yet increasingly astronomers and cosmologists seem to be invoking the multiverse to explain puzzling observations.